# How can be implemented a well working data replication strategy?

Tags: backup

How can be implemented a well working data replication strategy ?

I realize that this question may be a bit naive, but I dare ask because it's very important to me and, above all, I think relevant to many small office / home office user.

I take care, for free, of IT equipment of a medical office, held by a relative of mine. The most demanding task is to provide continuous data protection, keeping constantly backed up the mission critical archive of medical reports, continuously  modified each and every time a patient is examined.

1. It's extremely important to backup every single modification (es, when during the day ten modifications occur, I can't consider accptable to backup them at evening, because for many hour only one copy exists of one of them).
2. Every time a modification is performed a passord protected rar archive is generated. No problem with it.
3. The question is: how can I carefully store those rar files ?

A present moment:

4. each new rar file is automatically copied on a second hard disk inside the pc and a pen drive, whitout human intervention.
5. A couples time a week the data set is copied on an external hard disk.
6. Monthly the whole dataset is saved on a DVD, stored at home, not in office.
7. Backup during typing isn't required. It must happend only when the file is saved.
8. Only desktop and laptop computers are in use. No smartphone, tablet, etc.

Obvious vulnerability of the process:

9. Doesn't protect against ransomware: every device connected, for long or short time, can be, in principle, attacked
10. It's impracticable to fill the main strongbox, the dvd, every day. It would be too much time and money consuming, not to mention the requirement of physical space.

Can you, please, give some advices?

Comment: Veeam Backup & Replication. Can backup anything from OS to VM and it does in incrementally. You can keep as many restore points as you want and restore from any of them. Note that your question is not about security.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding the concept of "security": I considered the topic pertinent. Anyway, I would like an hint to learn the reason why backup policies are not a branch of cybersecurity. Where shoud I post, in general and specifically about the virtualizzazione you propose ?

Comment: Securing your backup is a different topic from making a correct backup in the first place. As some recommendations: use 7zip instead of rar. It's more secure and better overall in everything...and free. Also, your backup archives should be checked for integrity before being saved to a permanent media like a DVD. Instead of DVDs, just use a couple of large HDDs. I use 10TB drives that I keep in another location as off-line backup.

Comment: So basically you have 2 choices: use a professional solution which may prove expensive or improve your own current solution.

Comment: Thanks for replies ! Just a last hint, if may I ask for. Can 
a ransomeware ravage your 10 Tb hard disk simply at the moment they are connected and data are transferred ? That would frustrate the whole process and it's one of my biggest concerns.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of copies, but little in the way of backups. You'd be better off with something like BackBlaze for immediate backup then a solid commercial backup system doing offsite backups nightly or weekly. Incremental backups are essential, and they are best sent to secure cloud storage that offers versioning such as AWS S3. Versioning means that if your backups are corrupted or encrypted by a virus you can recover them to a point in time. Also, medical clinics can usually afford to pay for a professional, they probably have some liability if they lose data.